# mysql fill column from another table max value

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Say I have two tables:

forum post:

```
id  topicId  text        createTime
====================================
110   7     'blah blah'  111
111   7     'blah blah'  222
112   7     'blah blah'  333
113   9     'blah blah'  444
```

forum topic:

```
id  topicCloseTime
==================
7   ????
8   ????
```

I want to fill `?????`s in `forum topic` with the maximum of all posts' createTime in that topic (I mean the maximum of `createStamp` from `forum post` among all rows with the same `topicId`, for example id:7 would be 333). How is that possible? tnx

Comment: You could use triggers on `forum post` operations INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE, but, maybe it's just me, having a topicCloseTime suggests a topic is closed and no more post may be made.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UPDATE with a Correlated subquery (syntax might be wrong..give it a try):

```sql
UPDATE forumtopic ft 
SET ft.topicCloseTime = (SELECT MAX(fp.createTime) 
                         FROM forumpost fp 
                         WHERE fp.topicId = ft.Id)
```

Comment: it encounters this error: SQL Error (1136): Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Answer (score 0):

I would handle this via a join update:

```
UPDATE forumtopic ft
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT topicId, MAX(createTime) AS maxct
    FROM forumpost
    GROUP BY topicId
) fp
    ON ft.id = fp.topicId
SET
    ft.topicCloseTime = fp.maxct;
```

Comment: it show me this error: SQL Error (1136): Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: My code should not be generating this error, so I assume you are running something else.

Answer (score 0):

Join the table to the query that returns the max `createTime` for each `topicId`:

```
update topic t inner join (
  select topicId, max(createtime) createTime
  from post
  group by topicId
) p on p.topicId = t.id 
set t.topicCloseTime = p.createTime;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/obu1ySXBEybfXYgp9wvcEy/0).
Results:

```
| id  | topicCloseTime |
| --- | -------------- |
| 7   | 333            |
| 8   |                |
```

Comment: it show me this error, what am I missing? SQL Error (1136): Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: This is an UPDATE statement. Are you trying to INSERT?